# Smooth coloring\Normalized Iteration with Julia set - Python

Tags: python, fractals, mandelbrot

I've been working on making a julia set code with python. I didn't write the original code, but I modified it slightly and it achieves what I want it too... except smooth coloring! I've read on how to do it, but I'm still confused.

Code pre-color-smoothing attempt:

```
def julia():
    while True:
        try:
            julwidth = int(input("What width would you like the image? ex. 256, 512, etc. \nLarger numbers take longer to compute.\n"))
            julheight = int(input("What height would you like the image? ex. 256, 512, etc. \nLarger numbers take longer to compute.\n"))
            iter = int(input("Max iterations? If you don't know, 255 is a good number \n"))
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("Enter an integer, please")
    print("Running Julia fractal... please wait...")
    imgx = julwidth
    imgy = julheight
    image = Image.new("RGB", (imgx, imgy))

    # drawing area
    xa = -2.0
    xb = 2.0
    ya = -1.5
    yb = 1.5
    maxIt = iter # max iterations allowed
    Time = time.clock()
    #print(time)
    # find a good Julia set point using the Mandelbrot set
    while True:
        cx = random.random() * (xb - xa) + xa
        cy = random.random() * (yb - ya) + ya
        c = cx + cy * 1j
        z = c
        for i in range(maxIt):
            if abs(z) > 2.0:
                break 
            z = z * z + c
        if i > 10 and i < 100:
            break

    # draw the Julia set
    for y in range(imgy):
        zy = y * (yb - ya) / (imgy - 1)  + ya
        for x in range(imgx):
            zx = x * (xb - xa) / (imgx - 1)  + xa
            z = zx + zy * 1j
            for i in range(maxIt):
                if abs(z) > 2.0:
                    break 
                z = z * z + c
            red = i % 8 *32
            green = i % 16 * 16
            blue = i % 32 * 8
                #print(red, green, blue)
            image.putpixel((x, y), (red, green, blue))
    print("Done computing. \n")
```

With smoothing attempt:

```
def julia():
    while True:
        try:
            julwidth = int(input("What width would you like the image? ex. 256, 512, etc. \nLarger numbers take longer to compute.\n"))
            julheight = int(input("What height would you like the image? ex. 256, 512, etc. \nLarger numbers take longer to compute.\n"))
            iter = int(input("Max iterations? If you don't know, 255 is a good number \n"))
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("Enter an integer, please")
    print("Running Julia fractal... please wait...")
    imgx = julwidth
    imgy = julheight
    image = Image.new("RGB", (imgx, imgy))

    # drawing area
    xa = -2.0
    xb = 2.0
    ya = -1.5
    yb = 1.5
    maxIt = iter # max iterations allowed
    Time = time.clock()
    #print(time)
    # find a good Julia set point using the Mandelbrot set
    while True:
        cx = random.random() * (xb - xa) + xa
        cy = random.random() * (yb - ya) + ya
        c = cx + cy * 1j
        z = c
        for i in range(maxIt):
            if abs(z) > 2.0:
                break 
            z = z * z + c
            smooth = (abs(z))
        if i > 10 and i < 100:
            break

    # draw the Julia set
    for y in range(imgy):
        zy = y * (yb - ya) / (imgy - 1)  + ya
        for x in range(imgx):
            zx = x * (xb - xa) / (imgx - 1)  + xa
            z = zx + zy * 1j
            for i in range(maxIt):
                if abs(z) > 2.0:
                    break 
                z = z * z + c
                smooth += (abs(z))
                #print(smooth)
            red = ceil(smooth % 8 * 32)
            green = ceil(red*red)
            blue = ceil(green*red)
                #print(red, green, blue)
            image.putpixel((x, y), (red, green, blue))
    print("Done computing. \n")
```

If you can't tell, I added a variable called smooth that I'm using to try and smooth the colors with by using the complex number/variable, z
Running my code with the smoothing attempt yields something..... not what I want. It's a weird blue image and it's not good. How can I add smoothing to this? I probably don't have a good understanding of smoothing, so an explanation might help.

Answer (score 2):

Compute fractional escape counts and set the color according to that:

`ec = N + 1 - log (log |Z(N)|) / log 2` where N is the escape count when the value of `'z'` escaped, `Z(N)` is the value of `z`when it escaped and `|z|` is the modulus of `z` which is just `sqrt (x*x + y*y)`.